# Can we persist two different table entity in DynamoDB under one single transaction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, amazon-dynamodb

I have two tables in Amazon DynamoDB where I have to persist data in a single transaction Using spring boot. if the persistence fails in the second table it should rollback for the first table also.

I have tried looking into AWSLAB-amazon DynamoDB transaction but it only helps for a single table.

Comment: Add your code attempts in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try using the built-in DynamoDB [transactions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transactions.html) capability. From the limited information you give, it should do what you are looking for across regional tables. Just keep in mind that there is no rollback per se. Either all items in a transaction work or none of them. The internal transaction coordinator handles that for you though.

Now that this feature is out, you should not be looking at the AWSlabs tool most likely.